# Adding Context TO DI CreateScope

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, masstransit

In a console application I'm using masstransit to process messages coming from a rabbitMQ queue. Every message deals with a specific customer and contains a customterId (this could be in header or message, tbd).
I'm using standard Microsoft Dependency Injection and I have several services I wish to be scoped to this customer.

I can use IServiceProvider.CreateScope in the masstransit consumer. But I cannot seem to determine the proper way to set a specific "value" to a scope. Something that every scoped service provided can use to determine the customer for which the scope was defined. Something that the scoped service can use to determine the "context"

My feeling is that I am looking to define something like HttpContext (This off course is not available in console application).

Do I have to do this manually by setting properties on a scoped service on which all other (scoped) services have a dependency? That feels not very thread safe to me (what if a service is instantiated in a scope before I can set the customer property?).

I know this is a little open for a question here, yet maybe someone can still provide an answer?

I would provide code, but this more an architectural question and on internal the workings of MSDI.

Answer (score 2):

MassTransit creates a scope for every consumer, so creating another scope is a bad idea. Any scoped dependencies will be resolved through the consumer's constructor automatically by the container.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But that leaves the more general question on DI. Is there a place where I can put some value per scope that scoped services can use. If I put an customerId header on a message all scoped services should "know" the are working for that customer. Some kind of context to the scope.

Comment: There is an [entire sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters) on that subject.

Comment: I had seen that, but after rereading it, I think I understand it better now. Thanks